# How to rowspan with php with foreach loop

Tags: php, html

I have `$data` array with multiple rows and columns. Each row contains date and other info in other columns. I use foreach loop to draw every `<tr>` row (appending the to `$output`). Now, how to add `rowspan= $samedays` for same days?

If i compare current `$row` date to next day, I can get rowspan for no more than two days. Or I have to add it to every row. I need to count every identical days beforehand and then apply rowspan to first row and leave `<td>` empty for next days.

Below I have attached image of my unsuccessful results:
[atempt screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU0qx.jpg)
4r-1 = 4 day of week, r-1 = rowspan number.

```
foreach ( $data as $nr => $row ) {

        //converting UTC date to USER TIME ZOME! 
        $utc_date = $row[ 'dateTime' ];
        $date = new DateTime( $utc_date, new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) );
        $date->setTimeZone( new DateTimeZone( $tzone ) );
        $tzWeekDay = $date->format( 'N' ); //get DAY NUMBER
        $WeekNr = $date->format( 'W' ); //get WEEK number

        if ( isset( $data[ $nr + 1 ] ) ) {
            $next_row = $data[ $nr + 1 ]; // next element
        } else {
            $next_WeekDay = 0;
        }

        $next_utc_date = $next_row[ 'dateTime' ];
        $next_date = new DateTime( $next_utc_date, new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) );
        $next_date->setTimeZone( new DateTimeZone( $tzone ) );
        $next_WeekDay = $next_date->format( 'N' ); //get DAY NUMBER


        if ( $tzWeekDay == $next_WeekDay ) {
            $rowspan_nr++;
            $rowspan = 'rowspan=';
        } else {
            $rowspan_nr = 1;
            $rowspan = 'rowspan=';
        }
        $previousDay = $tzWeekDay;
```

```
$output .= '<tr >  
            <td>' . $nr . '-' . $WeekNr . '</td>
            <td ' . $rowspan . '""  >' . $tzWeekDay . 'r-' . $rowspan_nr . '</td>
            <td   class="dateTime ' . $weekend . ' " id="' . $row[ "id" ] . '"><input class="datepick" type="text" value="' . $tzDate . '"></td>  
            <td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question so that we can give suggestions as to how to achieve what your after.

Comment: So you want the date never to be repeated, with rowspan increased as much as needed? Or will rowspan only ever be one or two? Providing a [mcve] with sample data and desired output would help a lot.

Comment: @miken32 yeah, I want date (day of week, first column in example image) never to be repeated. I want rowspan to span across all fridays or sundays- kind of grouping data.